# Celery doesn't work when i import a module. Before importing it works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, celery

My celery task is to update the mongodb database. I've created a handler for it which i'm importing to celery.py. Celery seems to work fine but when i try to import the handler module it throws an error.
`django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet`

**celery.py:**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from django.conf import settings
import os
from celery import Celery
    
# from handlers.ordercount import OrderCount

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'di_idealsteel.settings')

app = Celery('di_idealsteel')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))

@app.task(bind=True)
def add(self,number,customer_id):
    ordercount = OrderCount()
    opencount = ordercount.open_enquiries(number,customer_id)
```

When i try to import **5th line** it throws this **error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ashish\envs\idealvenv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\ashish\envs\idealvenv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 437, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ashish\Desktop\Internship\di_idealsteel\di_idealsteel\celery.py", line 32, in add
    from handlers.ordercount import OrderCount
  File "C:\Users\Ashish\Desktop\Internship\di_idealsteel\handlers\ordercount.py", line 4, in <module>
    from handlers.user_handler import UserHandler
  File "C:\Users\Ashish\Desktop\Internship\di_idealsteel\handlers\user_handler.py", line 12, in <module>
    from app.models import (AuthUser,Customers,CustomerUsers,UserHistory,CustomerUsersHistory)
  File "C:\Users\Ashish\Desktop\Internship\di_idealsteel\app\models.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "c:\users\ashish\envs\idealvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "c:\users\ashish\envs\idealvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "c:\users\ashish\envs\idealvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "c:\users\ashish\envs\idealvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "c:\users\ashish\envs\idealvenv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

**Other files:**

`__init__.py:`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

**settings.py**:

```
# CELERY STUFF
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Africa/Nairobi'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in celery.py is causing the error -->
from handlers.ordercount import OrderCount

If you look at the error stacktrace, internally the OrderCount module/class is calling AbstractBaseUser model, from django.contrib.auth.models import User / AbstractBaseUser. And till now django hasn't had the chance to load all the apps inside its registry and you are trying to find the User model from the registry.

You can create a tasks.py file in your django app and register your tasks there.
You have to just remove the add celery task from celery.py file

Alternatively, you could also import OrderCount locally in the add function, to avoid the error.